# Get full path of executable of running process on HPUX

Tags: c++, c, hp-ux

I want to get the full path of the running process (executable) without having root permission using C++ code. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this.

on Linux platforms i can do it by using following way.

```
char exepath[1024] = {0};
char procid[1024] = {0};
char exelink[1024] = {0};

sprintf(procid, "%u", getpid());

strcpy(exelink, "/proc/");
strcat(exelink, procid);
strcat(exelink, "/exe");

readlink(exelink, exepath, sizeof(exepath));
```

Here exepath gives us the full path of the  executable.

Similarly for windows we do it using

```
GetModuleFileName(NULL, exepath, sizeof(exepath));  /* get fullpath of the service */
```

Please help me how to do it on HP-UX since there is no /proc directory in HP-UX.

Comment: why in the world wouldn't you create the string like this?: snprintf(exelink, sizeof(exelink), "/proc/%u/exe", getpid());

I see in your code 3 buffers and 4 lines dedicated to what should be 1 buffer and 1 line.

Answer (score 9):

First, I'd like to comment on your Linux solution: it is about 5 times as long as it needs to be, and performs a lot of completely unnecessary operations, as well as using 1024 magic number which is just plain wrong:

```
$ grep PATH_MAX /usr/include/linux/limits.h 
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name */
```

Here is a correct minimal replacement:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
  char exepath[PATH_MAX] = {0};
  readlink("/proc/self/exe", exepath, sizeof(exepath));
```

Second, on HP-UX you can use `shl_get_r()` to obtain information about all loaded modules. At index 0, you will find information about the main executable. The `desc.filename` will point to the name of the executable at `execve(2)` time.

Unfortunately, that name is relative, so you may have to search `$PATH`, and may fail if the application did `putenv("PATH=some:new:path")` or if the original exename was e.g. `./a.out` and the application has performed `chdir(2)` since.

Comment: Man seems to indicate that "readlink() does not append a null byte to buf. It will truncate the contents (to a length of bufsiz characters), in case the buffer is too small to hold all of the contents."

Answer (score 4):

On HP-UX, use pstat:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define _PSTAT64
#include <sys/pstat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char filename[PATH_MAX];
  struct pst_status s;

  if (pstat_getproc(&s,sizeof(s),0,getpid()) == -1) {
    perror("pstat_getproc");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (pstat_getpathname(filename,sizeof(filename),&s.pst_fid_text) == -1) {
    perror("pstat_getpathname");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("filename: %s\n",filename);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This example from HP, combines the standard approaches first,
then falling back to pstat:
http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=88086d6e1de021106d6e1de02110275d6e10RCRD

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answer referring to the Unix Programming FAQ was right.  The problem, even with the Linux /proc answer, is that the path to the executable may have changed since the exec().  In fact, the executable may have been deleted.  Further complications arise from considering links (both symbolic and hard) -- there may be multiple paths to the same executable. There is no general answer that covers all cases, since there may not be a path remaining, and if there is one it may not be unique.

That said, using argv[0] with some logic, as advocated by cjhuitt earlier, will probably do what you want 99.9% of the time.  I'd add a check for a path containing "/" before doing the relative path check (and note, you must do that before any cwd() calls).  Note that if your calling program is feeling mischievous, there's a host of things that can be done between fork() and exec() to mess this up. Don't rely on this for anything that could affect application security (like location of configuration files).

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose do you need the executable path?  Bear in mind, as I put in my earlier post, that there is no guarantee that a path to the executable will exist, or that it will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before in a general case.  The general idea is to grab argv[0], and do some processing on it:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  string full_prog_path = argv[0];
  if ( full_prog_path[0] == "/" )
  {   // It was specified absolutely; no processing necessary.
  }
  else
  {
    string check_cwd = getcwd();
    check_cwd += argv[0];
    if ( FileExists( check_cwd ) )
    { // It was specified relatively.
      full_prog_path = check_cwd;
    }
    else
    { // Check through the path to find it
      string path = getenv( "PATH" );
      list<string> paths = path.split( ":" );
      foreach( test_path, paths )
      {
        if ( FileExists( test_path + argv[0] ) )
        { // We found the first path entry with the program
          full_prog_path = test_path + argv[0];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  cout << "Program path: " << full_prog_path << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this has some assumptions that might break at some point, but it should work for most cases.

Comment: In the simple cases, this is fine.  However, it is not reliable.  I could write: execl("/path/to/your/program", "../../penguins/rule/the/world", "arg1", (char *)0); and the value of argv[0] bears no resemblance to the name of the executable.

Comment: @Jonathan: Like I said, it has some assumptions but works for most cases.  I don't know of any way of handling the scenario you mention in code.