# How to find a working directory of running process(HPUX/Solaris/Linux/AIX)

Tags: unix, process

Trying to get the home directory of running process.
For Linux, I learned that I could use /proc/PID/exe information, but I think there is no that information in other OS.

Assuming that there is no file information $PATH, can you let me know how I can get the home directory of the running process?
I just need to assume that OS utilities usage is very limited in OS, meaning that I should use very common command.

Condition:
No special utility such as lsof.

## Added

The process I am referring is the process a 3rd-party application runs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column for `ps -ef` (the most common useful-options, in POSIX) give you the process owner, usually a name (sometimes only the uid number).  For
example

```
UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD                           
statd      1935      1  0 04:00 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rpc.statd               
101        2329      1  0 04:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system 
daemon     2511      1  0 04:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd                 
avahi      2540      1  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [vmw-de>
avahi      2541   2540  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper   
bind       2593      1  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/named -u bind       
kdm        2781   2780  0 04:01 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdm_gre>
www-data   2903   2782  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start    
www-data   2904   2782  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start    
www-data   2905   2782  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start    
www-data   2906   2782  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start    
www-data   2908   2782  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start    
ntp        2989      1  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/nt>
postgres   3059      1  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/p>
postgres   3063   3059  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process     >
postgres   3064   3059  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process >
postgres   3065   3059  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher>
postgres   3066   3059  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector pro>
104        3555      1  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m     
gitlog     3677   3676  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/git-daemon
116        3679   3676  0 04:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon
```

The process owner name (or uid number) are in `/etc/passwd` as the first column (for the *name*) or the third column (uid number).  Columns in `/etc/passwd` are delimited by colons (`:`).  For example:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash                                            
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
messagebus:x:101:105::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
colord:x:102:106:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
usbmux:x:103:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/home/usbmux:/bin/false
Debian-exim:x:104:111::/var/spool/exim4:/bin/false
statd:x:105:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
avahi:x:106:114:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
```

In this example, `statd` is

```
statd:x:105:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
```

The next-to-last column of `/etc/passwd` is the home directory of the process, e.g., `/var/lib/nfs` for the `statd` process.

Some system processes have no home directory, e.g., you may see `/usr/sbin` on Linux systems, or some other directory that several processes share.

Further reading:

- [POSIX ps](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) shows the options of POSIX `ps`, implemented in these systems:
- [HPUX ps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=HP-UX%2011.22&arch=default&format=html)
- [Solaris ps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%205.10&arch=default&format=html)
- [Linux ps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SuSE%20Linux%2Fi386%2011.3&arch=default&format=html)
- [AIX ps](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/ps.htm)
- [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) shows the file-format of `/etc/passwd`

OP amended question to indicate that the *current directory* (rather than home-directory) is wanted.  Systems using a proc-filesystem can provide this information.  Those are Solaris, AIX and Linux.

However, HPUX does not (see for example [/proc on HP-UX?](http://community.hpe.com/t5/General/proc-on-HP-UX/td-p/2762959?notmigrated), which says the `pstat` system-call can be used).  I do not see a possibility, reading its [manual page](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man2/pstat.2.html), but the link below says `pstat_getpathname` will work.

AIX supports it, according to [IBM documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.files/proc.htm).

Look for the `cwd` "file" for the working directory of a given process in systems with a proc-filesystem.

Further reading:

- [Find out current working directory of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process)
- [current working directory of process](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Languages-and-Scripting/current-working-directory-of-process/td-p/5093802)
- [Get full path of executable of running process on HPUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200737/get-full-path-of-executable-of-running-process-on-hpux)
- [A sample of a program that can find itself (getcwd getenv)](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=88086d6e1de021106d6e1de02110275d6e10RCRD)

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. But, I need to find the location of process running, the process is not native OS process. For example if there is a process named run_it_first of any other 3rd party application, and it is launched from /usr/userapp/bin/run_it_first, I need to get '/usr/userapp/bin' value. Thanks.

Comment: That is called the "current working directory", not the "home directory".  Solaris and Linux have proc-filesystems from which you could get this information (I don't recall HPUX and AIX as being possible).

Comment: Maybe the question refers to the location of the executable file?

Comment: Hi, @Thomas. Thanks for your clear explanation. I am looking for pstat_getpathname further to accomplish this requirement. Once it is done, I think I can share it. Thanks again.

Comment: The example code shown in [this page](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Languages-and-Scripting/current-working-directory-of-process/td-p/5093802) seems plausible, but I did not test it.